# Firefox Download limit

Tags: firefox, download, about-config

I know you can queue up all the downloads in firefox and if you keep adding them, they just keep downloading.
I know I can pause a download and let one finish and then start the other one.
But is there a way, maybe an entry in about:config that can help me limit how many downloads to allow going on.
I know I can use a download manager but I'm just curious about this.
I am not asking for a bandwidth limit tip but instead a download number limit tip.
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to limit the number of downloads in the first place?

Comment: So you can start accessing / using individual files earlier, instead of all of them later?

Answer (score 4):

Try finding **network.http.max-connections-per-server** in about:config and reducing the value.

Answer (score 2):

There are two limits in Firefox (and all XulRunner apps) - Maximum number of connections overall, and max connections per server.

see **network.http.max-connections** and **network.http.max-connections-per-server** in about:config

(Adding to Damian's answer; will vote his up once I have some rep...)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a download manager - something like download them all - this will give you the control you're after, and a bunch more.

Limiting your max-connections will do the job, but if I understand correctly will also limit how many files you can download when browsing and slow down web-pages (probably not the effect you're after).